# XSL transformation: Using translate and substring-after in XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

I am stumped and any assistance is much appreciated. I am trying to capture an email value from a XML field but I am not getting the desired output.

I have this XML field:

```
<Rmk>EMAIL-FIRST.LAST*ABX.COM</Rmk>
```

I have this XSL statement:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//Rmk[starts-with(.,'EMAIL-')]">
<Email>
<xsl:value-of select="translate(substring-after(.,'EMAIL-'),'*','@')"/>
</Email>
</xsl:for-each>
```

The output it produces is `FIRST.LAST*ABX.COM` while the desired output is `FIRST.LAST@ABX.COM`. Any input?

Comment: The `translate` call looks correct to me. Which XSLT processor do you use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using your data on http://xslfiddle.net and:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="//Rmk[starts-with(.,'EMAIL-')]">
            <Email>
                <xsl:value-of select="translate(substring-after(.,'EMAIL-'),'*','@')"/>
            </Email>
        </xsl:for-each>  
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

for the transform yields the result

```
<Email>FIRST.LAST@ABX.COM</Email>
```

which seems to be the result you desire. What else is wrong?